# How to set a class-wide variable that is referenced within the classes methods

Tags: python

I'm a little bit new to python and programming in general so I'm not sure if I'm using the terminology correctly but,

I have a short program that I am writing that will read the words in a text file, split them into an array and then output only words with a specified length.

However, I have run into an issue when trying to set up the array and file variables. While overall the program works, in each function I am re-instantiating the file variable (File = open() to File.close) and I am wondering if there is any way to make the variables class-wide.

I have tried making them class-wide by indenting before the functions, but then I get an error because `name` and `set_length` have not been instantiated yet.

As I said, this is one of the first times I am working with classes, so any advice would be helpful. Thanks!

```
class FileParser:

    def __init__(self,name,set_length):
        self.name = name
        self.set_length = set_length

    def Print_words(self):

        File = open(self.name, "r")
        Allwords = File.read()
        words = Allwords.split("\n")
        File.close()

        for word in words:
            if len(word) <= self.set_length:
                print(word)

    def length_counter(self):

        File = open(self.name, "r")
        Allwords = File.read()
        words = Allwords.split("\n")
        File.close()

        x = 0

        for word in words:
            x += 1
        text = "there are {} many words in this file".format(x)
        return text
```

Comment: It shouldn't be class-wide, since each instance reads a different file. Put it in `self.all_words`

Comment: BTW, the last loop should just be `x = len(words)`

Comment: The `file` variable is completely incidental. You're only using that to populate the `words` variable, the latter being all you care about. And it's a bad waste of resources to read from the file repeatedly when you don't have to. You should make a single method that does the file reading, call it only once when the instance is initialised, and save the contents in an instance variable such as `self.words`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't be a class variable, since each `FileParser` instance reads a different file.

You can read the file in the `__init__` method and assign the list of words to an instance attribute.

```
class FileParser:

    def __init__(self,name,set_length):
        self.name = name
        self.set_length = set_length
        with open(name, "r") as f:
            data = f.read()
        self.words = data.split("\n")

    def Print_words(self):
        for word in self.words:
            if len(word) <= self.set_length:
                print(word)

    def length_counter(self):
        text = "there are {} many words in this file".format(len(self.words))
        return text
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. What exactly does the with statement do? Is it like a combination of opening and closing a file or am I getting that wrong?

Comment: That's exactly what it is. https://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm